# Laravel nested foreach by using multiple objects

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I want to use some data in profile page that I successfully can pass those data to the view

```
    return view('pages.profile' , compact('data' , 'faculty' , 'scores' , 'sub' , 'finance_r'));
```

But when I want to use nested for each to print "sub" data in to the foreach base on the "data" section I got an error

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
```

The simplest thing that I want to do

```
@foreach ($data as $data)
  @foreach ($sub as $sub)
    {{ $sub->id }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I find this on the laravel Docs but it doesn't work

```
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->posts as $post)
        @if ($loop->parent->first)
            This is first iteration of the parent loop.
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

How we can able to use a foreach in side the other foreach?

**NOTE** : all data that I pass to view are Object.
My sub data is

```
Collection {#865 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => Subject {#856 ▼
      #table: "subject"
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 8
        "name" => "پروگرامینگ"
        "number_of_credites" => 5
        "semester_id" => 1
        "faculty_id" => 2
      ]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Subject {#857 ▶}
    2 => Subject {#858 ▶}
```

And my data

```
    Collection {#848 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Scores {#844 ▼
      #table: "scores"
      +timestampes: false
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "subject_id" => 15
        "score" => 100
        "scores_student_details_id" => 7
        "created_at" => "2018-04-09 15:02:24"
        "updated_at" => "2018-04-09 15:02:21"
```

I actually want to print sub according to the `"faculty_id" => 1`

Comment: You are using `$users` for foreach. Have you send it to view from controller?

Comment: Where are you getting the `$loop` variable from? Are you sure this is where you're throwing your error? Within your code you provided you don't seem to be attempting to access an `id` property anywhere.

Comment: @Nasser Ali Karimi for which object you need to do nested foreach?

Comment: @HirenGohel I saw that all data is available in the view just I got error when I want to use nested for each

Comment: @domdambrogia I saw that i got that code in the Laravel docs that not working for me

Comment: @ChiragPatel I want to use a foreach based on the $sub inside the other foreach based on $data object.

Comment: dump your `$sub` by dd($sub) and show that in your question.

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi Have you defined relations between data and sub? if defined then please show them also

Comment: Sorry I send wrong data

Comment: @ChiragPatel Now I update question and the relation is on subject_id

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi I have given my answer. can you review it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are giving the same name in foreach loop.

You can do as per your code by doing this,

```
@foreach ($data as $value)
  @foreach ($sub as $subValue)
    {{ $subValue->id }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But this is not good practice,

Based on my opinion, you have to change your variable's name in your controller,
like you can pass `datas` instead of `data`, `subs` instead of `sub`,

```
 return view('pages.profile' , compact('datas' , 'faculty' , 'scores' , 'subs' , 'finance_r'));
```

And then you can do foreach loop,

```
@foreach ($datas as $data)
      @foreach ($subs as $sub)
        {{ $sub->id }}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> Always give your variable names relevant to your variable's work (singular/plural).

Try this and comment if you have any doubts.