# Laravel nested foreach by 2 different Models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745409/laravel-nested-foreach-by-using-multiple-objects). problem is, How to foreach data from different Models?

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\zainsurgalt\resources\views\choices\index.blade.php)

**Controller**

```
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get();
$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('question_number')->toArray();
return view('choices.index',compact('duplicates','choices'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                @foreach ($choices as $choice)
                    {{ $choice->question_number }}
                @endforeach
            </td>
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ $choice->id }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

**result of dd($choices) before foreach**

```
array:34 [▼
0 => 5
1 => 5
2 => 0
3 => 0
4 => 0
...
31 => 0
32 => 0
]
```

**Added this Controller full code**

```
public function index(Choice $choice){

    $duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get();
    $choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('question_number');
    $user = Choice::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
    if ($user === null) {
        $too = 0;
        return redirect()->route('choices.create');
    }
    else{
        $too = 1;
        return view('choices.index',compact('too','duplicates','choices'));
    }
}
```

**Full code of View**

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:106px; width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5" scope="col">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><b>Шалгалтын цаг сонголт</b></h3>
            <select style="text-align: center;" name="time" class="form-control"> 
                    <option value="30:01">30 минут</option>
                    <option value="40:01">40 минут</option>
                    <option value="50:01">50 минут</option>
                    <option value="60:01">60 минут</option>
                    <option value="70:01">70 минут</option>
                    <option value="80:01">80 минут</option>
                    <option value="90:01">90 минут</option>
            </select></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">№</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">Нэр</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">Нийт асуултын тоо</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">Асуултын тоо</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (array_combine($duplicates->toArray(), $choices->toArray()) as $duplicate => $choice){
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $choice->question_number }}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ $choice->id }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

brwanobr oawnbrnoawbn obrawnor bonb rwanobrwn obrawnobrw aonbanobnaowbonwab onbonawb onrwa onbr awnob rwnobrno rbawnorb noawbnorba nobrwaonbrwa

Comment: Please dump your variable before your loop starts and check the output. You can use laravel `dd($variable)` function to do this.

Comment: when i `dd($choices)` it gives me right datas.

Comment: Please check my updated question please. @srimaln91

Comment: Your foreach loop looks correct. But your `dd($choices)` only returns array of integer, while you are trying to access it like `$choice->question_number`. Try to change it to just `{{ $choice }}`in your foreach choices loop.

Comment: @JoshuaStephen same error sir.

Comment: please append `topic` and  `topic.choices` method to your question.

Comment: There are several errors in your logic: 1) you want to link topics and choices but it's not so clear how, maybe you should use relationships, and 2) the error you are getting is because $choice is out of context, out of your inner loop. Please specify what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

**1 solution**

You are using the choice id in the blade file but on the query, you are not loading the id 
So need to load the id and question_number both

```
$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get(['id','question_number'])->toArray();
```

Also when you use **toArray()** you need to change the

**From** `{{ $choice->question_number }}`

**TO** `{{ $choice['question_number'] }}`

same for the  choices edit link `href="choices/{{ $choice['id'] }}/edit"`

Or just remove the `toArray()` from the query.

**2 solution**

Now if you want to load the choice along with the topic and you have topic id in the choice model

```
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get(); // Id for this table is your question number or any realtion between the Question Model and Choice Model
$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('question_number','topic_id')->toArray();
return view('choices.index',compact('duplicates','choices'));


@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
             {{ isset($choices[$duplicate->topic->id]) ? $duplicate->topic->id : '' }}
        </td>
        <td>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ isset($choices[$duplicate->topic->id]) ? $choices[$duplicate->topic->id] : '' }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i want to use 2 collection in 1 foreach. please help. then let me accept your answer.

Comment: Yes you can. any realtion between the Question Model and Choice Model?
It's seems that you have? It seems that it have with topic and then choice
so topic hasOne realtion with choice or hasMany?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('question_number')->toArray();
```

with `$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();`
as when you pluck you won't get the key `question_number`
and will get the error `trying t o get property of undefined`

Comment: care to add an explanation?

Comment: Good news It almost works, I looped data. but bad news. i looped data for each line. It's like i printed all `data` in column 1, and also printed all `data` in column 2.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want? and if this works for you then please accept the answer.

Comment: i want foreach 2 collection in 1 foreach. its like. `@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)` and `{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}` and `{{ $choice->question_number }}`

Comment: You can use relationship for choice in the first query itself
like `with(['choice' => function($q) {
$q->where('user_id',Auth::id());
});`

Answer (score 1):

trying to access `$choice->id` out of foreach loop in your view

you have used **pluck()** in your controller

so in your view you can't use `$choice->question_number`

so you need to change controller
    query  or you can use below

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
  @foreach ($choices as $choice)
  // here only can use like this
      {{ $choice }}
      //{{ $choice->question_number }}
    @endforeach           

// this $choice->id out of foreach loop
<a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ $choice->id }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td> 
@endforeach
```

or as @Mayuri Pansuriya said you need to change your controller query then you can access

```
$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
```

then you can access in your view

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
       @foreach ($choices as $choice)
           {{ $choice->question_number }}
       @endforeach
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller don't use toArray() if you want both items to be objects. The best way I know of to do this in the view is to use array_combine() if the objects are the same length.

Controller

```
$duplicates = Question::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")->with('topic', 'topic.choices')->groupBy('topic_id')->get()->toArray();
$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get()->toArray();
return view('choices.index',compact('duplicates','choices'));
```

View

```
@for($i=0; $i< count($duplicates); $i++){
   <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicates[$i]['topic']['id'] }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicates[$i]['topic']['title'] }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicates[$i]['total'] }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $choices[$i]['question_number'] }}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ $choices[$i]['id'] }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
    </tr>
@endfor
```

The error you showed is from trying to access an array using object syntax:

`{{ $choice->question_number }}`

`$choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('question_number');`

If that is the only problem, then just don't use toArray() on the collection and leave it as an object or use array syntax.

Comment: In `foreach` that gives error like `Array to string conversion`

Comment: **view controller model** ?

Comment: Updated my answer. The crux of it is that you need to parse through one at the same rate as the other. As someone else mentioned though I think you should consider creating a relation in your model so you can have everything you need in one query. You should also use get() instead of pluck since you are using id and question_number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174203/discussion-between-oneliner-and-ruka-xing).

Answer (score 0):

Better Join all those tables and keeep it in a single variable .Then pass the joins on view with compact()on controller method.then,do the foreach by keeping one variable.This makes you clean and better.