# Laravel 5.3 foreach 2 collections from 2 diffrent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**View**

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
     @foreach($choices as $choice)
     <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $choice->question_number }}</td>
     <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ $choice->id }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
     @endforeach
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**I want result like**

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->id }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->topic->title }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $duplicate->total }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $choice->question_number }}</td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="choices/{{ $choice->id }}/edit">Шинэчлэх</a></td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

> i want result like @foreach(duplicates as $duplicate, $choices as $choice) this. but i know i will get error. but how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
@foreach (array_combine($duplicates->toArray(), $choices->toArray()) as $duplicate => $choice){
    // Do some stuff
@endforeach
```

If Laravel's blade syntax doesn't allow for this then you can always generate the html in pure PHP and forgo the blade syntax. This is all assuming that $duplicates and $choices are both query objects, which from your code they seem to be.

Comment: `array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\zainsurgalt\resources\views\choices\index.blade.php)`

Comment: Revised. They need toArray(). You will access the values in array syntax inside your loop, unless you cast it back to an object. They will need to be the same length also. If not then you will have to manually parse through them.

Comment: 1 is array 1 is not array. let me try something. i be right back.

Comment: now these are 2 arrays. but giving me error like `Array to string conversion` @OneLiner

Comment: what are you doing with the arrays? eg: what is your code inside of the loop? That error means basically that you are trying to echo an array, so something that you are trying to use as a value is an array with your value inside I believe.

Comment: Please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015571/laravel-nested-foreach-by-2-different-models

Comment: If you need to see the structure of the arrays then either var_dump($duplicates) or print_r();

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using Eloquent: Relationships?
I dont have pc right here so I have not genarated a example to test this, but I hope it would be some useful.

[laravel eloquent relationships docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: So i can use that but in controller, how to take to `collection` in Controller

Comment: We can push new child to collection. for example $duplicate->question_number = $choice->question_number. then you can use in blade as a new element.